# Adding floating point numbers, why is this the result?

Tags: math, floating-point

Suppose we wanted to add the IEEE 754 floating point numbers:

1.00101 • 2<sup>2</sup> and -1.00111 • 2<sup>3</sup>

We first adjust the first number to match exponents: 1.00101 • 2<sup>2</sup> = 0.100101 • 2<sup>3</sup>

The we add together to obtain -101.001, which we can convert to a floating point approximation.

Can someone explain how we add together to obtain the result -101.001, I'm having a hard time understanding how this number was obtained and would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the signs just to make it easier (we'll switch it back in the end), following this logic:

```
a + -b = c --> -(a + -b) = -c --> -a + b = -c
```

Then add them: (which is really subtraction)

```
  1.001110
- 0.100101
----------
  0.101001
```

Then you have `-0.101001` • 2<sup>3</sup> = `-101.001`.